# Active mode with Kie Executor Server

Tags: drools

I'm a newbie of Kie architecture. I'm using Workbench with Executor Server (7.2 final)

Reading the Drools on line documentation Kie Session can be executed both in  Passive and Active modes.

But when working with the Executor Server  I've not found any REST API nor configuration parameters allowing to configure sessions running in Active mode.
Is there a way to set Active Mode in Executor Server sessions?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to Stateful and stateless kieSession ? I never came across term active and passive kieSession. Will you please share document with us

Comment: Hi, I read this:
https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html
chapter 7.5